# How to cancel a job in PHP-RESQUE

Tags: php-resque

I am using the below library

https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

How to cancel the running job. I tried to get the worker object and kill the child..but the object does not have any child.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep to put this in a comment and not an answer, but maybe this will help you:
http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/killing-stale-or-stuck-resque-jobs

Comment: Is there any method in the library that kills the process..instead of using command line?

Comment: kill -9 'pid_number' ?? although you will need to know pid number of specific job

Comment: i was expecting php-resque had a method to kill it...so kill is for unix command line right? yes i can get the pid from the Resque_Worker object.